# Can we say "I am on my way to being an expert at it"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

Can we use the phrase "I am on my way" in this context?

> **I am on my way** to being an expert at it

Comment: You can if you want to. It's not great prose. It's a bit wordy and not very neat. Most people would say **becoming an expert** rather than **being an expert**.  If you said: **I'm gradually becoming an expert at it**, you'd be saying the same thing in fewer words.

Comment: In informal contexts, like speaking, in an SMS or a personal email, this is quite natural to me, a Canadian native speaker.

Comment: Sounds good, but pretty colloquial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "on my way" part is fine. It's the second part of the sentence that throws it off. I would change it to:

> I'm on my way to **becoming** an expert.

Implicit in the sentence is that you're following some kind of process such as school or training. The process will ultimately qualify you as an expert. You can't "be" an expert if you haven't completed the process yet. During the process, you are "becoming an expert." Once you've completed the process, then you can say you "are an expert."

You will frequently see **well** used to qualify **on my way**. For example:

> I am **well on my way** to becoming an expert.